# Can't get list of wordpress pages using specific template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am trying to create a select box with options that are all the pages on wordpress using a specific template.

The template file name is **property.php** and in relation to the theme folder it is in `/page-templates/property.php`

I have the code working, returning all the page names until I specify the template name.

I have even added

```
<?php echo get_page_template(); ?>
```

to the **property.php** template to get the template name from wordpress itself.

I've tried **property.php** `/page-template/property.php`, `page-template/property.php` and even the entire file name from the root folder (which is what `get_page_template()` returns) but still nothing.

I can only assume I'm missing something entirely obvious.

```
<select id='cottage' name='cottage'>
    <?php
        $args = array('hierarchical' => 0, 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'property.php'); 

        $pages = get_pages($args);

        foreach($pages as $page)
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $page->post_title . "'>" . $page->post_title . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting to know it is:

`page-templates/property.php`